# "An error occurred while handling textDocument/didClose" error message with dart

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I've been teaching myself dart and flutter recently, and i'm using vscode. At random times i'll get this error message notification produced by vscode while coding dart that says An "error occurred while handling textDocument/didClose". I haven't payed attention enough to notice a trend in when it happens, and it happens some days all the time, and some not at all. Does anyone know any info about this at all?

Comment: It's a bug in the Dart SDK - See https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/3625 and https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/48051